# My sr.readline() is not reading the third line in a message? (Message sent to my server)

Tags: c#, string, networking, server, streamreader

```
            int i = 0;
            string line = null;
            string line = "";
            string line = "";
            while (i < 20)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (line1 == null)
                    {
                        line1 = sr.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        line2 += sr.ReadLine();
                    }

                }
                catch
                {

                }
                i++;
            }
```

So I have this code that receives a message. the message that is sent to me is:
"POST /Person HTTP/1.0\r\nContent-Length: 15\r\n\r\nis being tested\r\n"

Basically line1 takes in "POST /PERSON HTTP/1.0" and line2 should take in "Content-Length: 15nis being tested" except line2 actually takes in "Content-Length: 15".

Now I'm very confused on why this is happening as with other messages, it returns normally. But this one never gives me the 3rd line (When it should). I have noticed that the other messages only contained two lines, and this one contains 3 or 4 (the "\r\n" etc).
It should work what I have done already. I mean it loops way more than enough times to make sure. So I have no idea why it wont grab the third line.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you saying it hangs and never returns the 3rd line?  Or that the 3rd line is empty?  If the latter, that would be expected, and you'd have to call `ReadLine` again to get the 4th line "is being tested\r\n".

Comment: I run the readline command 20 times as seen in the while-loop. I cant actually debug or send my own arguments either so it's proven harder for me to figure out. And when I do send my own message, the "\r\n" are different, they actually show in the message when they shouldn't so I'm not sure.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful. This code doesn't even compile even as a snippet: you can't declare a variable three times `string line = null; string line = ""; string line = "";` and where is `line1`. Furthermore, you should be checking for more data, not blindly calling `ReadLine` and swallowing errors

Comment: messages come from a server allowed to me. You're correct about the try-catch actually. I should check that for errors. It's a server, that intakes a message from a stream reader. I can't really provide an example myself as when I try to recreate the message it actually shows the strings when sent to my own server. but one were if that message is sent, and readline() reads each line is the perfect replica of that